# LINQ string incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my stored procedure code and error is Input string is incorrect.
LINQ string may have an error.
Can any one help me point error.

```
  public ActionResult TeacherDashboard()
        {
            List<AttendanceModel> data = new List<AttendanceModel>();
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AttendanceConnect"].ToString();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getUserDetails", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        con.Open();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                data = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                        select new AttendanceModel()
                        {
                            UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserId"].ToString()),
                            UserRole = dr["UserRole"].ToString(),
                            Email = dr["Email"].ToString(),
                            Password = dr["Password"].ToString(),
                            Mobile = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Mobile"].ToString()),
                            isActive = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["isActive"].ToString())
                        }).ToList();
            }
            return View(data.ToList());
        }
```

This is my View Code and trying to use Jquery DataTable. But code stops at Input string is incorrect that is LINQ code.Can anyone help me know where have I gone wrong.

```
@model IEnumerable<AttendanceManagement.Models.AttendanceModel>   
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TeacherDashboard";
}
<h2>Tables</h2>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<table  id="attendanceUser" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserRole)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isActive)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mobile)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserRole)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isActive)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mobile)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.UserId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>


</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#attendanceUser').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you run the sp directly and post the results. My thought is the error is in that conversion `Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserId"].ToString())`, `Convert.ToInt32(dr["Mobile"].ToString())`, `Convert.ToBoolean(dr["isActive"].ToString())` one of the value is not in correct format

Comment: what do you mean by "input-string is incorrect"? What do you exoect and what do you get instead?

Comment: say if mobile number is `+1-140-236-2345` when you try to convert this to integer you get that error.

Comment: This means when you are calling Convert.ToInt32 with invalid input like "abc'" or null. This errro will return

Comment: I would start by trying to remove the ASP.NET part of this. Can you reproduce the same issue in a console app? If so, you can remove the view entirely, for a start. As always, diagnosing an error is a matter of divide and conquer.

Comment: I suspect it's something wrong in the conversion between sql server types and C# types. I suggest in the part where you assing value to data, replace LINQ expression `from r in rows select ...` with a iteration of the rows (foreach), and inside it actively instantiate a new AttendanceModel, then explicitly assign each field to it, using the dot. In the end add each new model to a list. This way you can debug step by step, with F10, and see where it will eventually break, and on what value.

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty your solution is right I went wrong in conversion of string